# Check of Meteor Template has rendered

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to check if a specific Template has been rendered, other than by using Sessions, i.e. the Template is accessible for other external functions to use?

A good example is that I want to use Blaze.renderWithData, but need to know that the Template is availabel beforehand.

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve this issue, maybe using `Session`?

Comment: Yes, but wanted to know if there was a different way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if a template has been rendered, put a flag in the `onRendered` callback. If you don't like Session vars use a reactive var or dict & include the inverse in the `onDestroyed`. Store that reactive-whatever under your package object's global. As an alternative, if you know where it might be rendered to, you can use `Blaze.getView` on the element where it should appear and if it returns, you know you have it, e.g. `Blaze.getView($('.foo')[0])`

Also consider asking yourself why you can't use spacebars or embed the rendering directly in the `onRendered` callback. Using `Blaze.renderWithData` is fairly uncommon.

Comment: The reason for using Blaze.renderWithData is because I have multiple areas of the screen that use this temnplate. The first use of the template can be rendered on page load, however, subsequent uses of the same template are user-initiated.